# Django Как в блоге помечать прочитанные новости

Tags: python, база-данных, django

Пишу на Django для своего сайта раздел новостей. Вот не могу понять, как удобнее сделать оповещение пользователей о новых новостях. Точнее как помечать что пользователь прочитал новость, или нет.

Как вариант думаю сделать модель содержащую поля user_id, news_id, которая будет отвечать что user_id прочел news_id.

Возможно есть решения попроще?

Comment: Попроще вроде нету, только делайте такое через ManyToManyField

Answer (score 0):

предлагаю такое решение
для модельки USER создать поле read_news в которым будут хранится ID прочитанных новостей. важно чтобы массив был сортирован. то есть для проверки в худчем случае понадобиться log(n) -времени. если использовать бинарный поиск.

к счатью для питонистов есть модуль bisect

```
from bisect import bisect
```

худшая проверка займет logn - времени где n - длина массива

Comment: Как-то сложно получилось

Comment: @andreymal может быть, но плюс будет в производительности. Если поставит связь ManyToMany то джанго создаст дополнительную связующую таблицу, где в данном случае будет поля user_id, post_id.